# database support in Samsung galaxy gear 2

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I wanted to know which database does the Samsung Galaxy Gear 2 support.  Gear 2 being based on Tizen I tried using the Web SQL  database. However on the emulator it shows that the [Web SQL](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/storage_guide/web_sql_database.htm) is not supported.

Can anyone tell me which database is supported for the Gear 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways get this done ..
HTML5 Webstorage, IndexedDB and good old Files . More importantly, the Tizen wearable sdk comes with sample code

HTML5 WebStorage Example.

Since your apps are written in HTLM5 and compiles using a webbrowser-like runtime engine, you can use the HTML5 Web storage paradigm for data storage and retrieval.

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

You can read more about it here ..
http://denvycom.com/blog/how-to-store-data-in-your-gear-2-apps/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to persist data would be on your phone. All communication 100% goes through Bluetooth to your phone via SAP. You can send data to your phone and have your integrated android app handle the db.