# Storing Accelerometer data in Tizen App

Tags: c++, database, html, sqlite, tizen

I'm writing my bachelor and am trying to do some fall detection with Samsung Devices. I do however know little of C++ and HTML5, which seems to be the only languages supported by Tizen as of now. And I have never worked with Databases. (My main focus up until now has been Unity C#)

**My question is;**

If I want to store accelerometer data when e.g. a button is pressed on a device, what would be a good approach? Is SQLITE the only way to go, or are there any simpler solutions?

Comment: You may be interested by [MonoTizen](https://github.com/kitsilanosoftware/MonoDevelop.Tizen), and your answer seems to be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791966/database-support-in-samsung-galaxy-gear-2)

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!